# Send message to tmux properly

Tags: vimscript, tmux

I am trying to send a message to a running tmux window that is side by side, to tell it to run a script when I press a button. What I am trying to do is done by doing:

```
silent !tmux send -t 0.1 ruby test.rb ENTER
```

Which will silently run the script. However, the display goes blank or glitches whenever I run this, and I than need to run the redraw! command to display the buffer again.

What would be the best way to convert these commands into a function?

```
:silent !tmux send -t 0.1 'ruby test.rb ENTER' 
:redraw!
```

so far I have tried doing the following, but I seem to be messing up somewhere:

```
silent !tmux send -t 0.1 ruby test.rb ENTER <CR> redraw! <CR> 
silent exec "tmux send -t 0.1 'ruby test.rb ENTER' | redraw!"
```

Overall, I am wondering what the best way to achieve sending messages to a tmux window would be and if this is a somewhat correct method, what is the proper way to build a vim function peicing that together?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be more about tmux than vi/vim.

Comment: @HerbWolfe The phrasing may be a bit off from what I'm trying to say, my bad. I'm more just looking to find out if there's a better way to send an external shell command from within vim and if not, how I can properly format it into a vimscript function.

Comment: @Jack You may want to review this Vim Tips wiki entry: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts

Answer (score 4):

After messing around a bit more and looking over some stuff I was able to get this to work by wrapping the external command and its parameters in an `execute` command then using the bar to send the redraw command.

```
:execute  "silent !tmux send -t 0.1 'ruby test.rb' Enter" | :redraw!
```